# Angular 2 - Consuming restful api calls with windows authentication

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-services

I have a .net web api hosted on IIS 7 on a remote server which uses windows authentication. I want to access the web api using **Angular 2 using TypeScript with node**. Earlier i was getting an error **'Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource'**

I added this on the hosted Application's web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 </customHeaders>
```

**But now i get Unauthorised 401 error. I have read about adding the following code to allow cross domain access - but I don't have any idea where do i add this in the angular 2 app and how to compile.**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,     Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
// Handle the get for this route
});
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
// Handle the post for this route
});
```

Here is the sample code for service that I am trying to make the get call with

```
@Injectable() 
export class TodoService {
todos$: Observable<Todo[]>; 
private _baseUrl: string;
private _todosObserver: Observer<Todo[]>;
private _dataStore: {
    todos: Todo[]
};

constructor(private _http: Http) {
    //let headers: Headers = new Headers();

    this._baseUrl = 'http:/SampleServer/Server/api/LoadTodo';
  this.todos$ = new Observable(observer => this._todosObserver = observer).share();
  this._dataStore = { todos: [] };
}

loadTodos() {
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    //headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
        btoa('username:password'));
    //let opts: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();

    //opts.headers = headers;
    this._http.get(`${this._baseUrl}`,headers).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this._dataStore.todos = data;
        this._todosObserver.next(this._dataStore.todos);
    }, error => console.log('Could not load todos.'));
}
```

Any help to resolve this issue would be great.

Comment: I don't know windows authentication but the above code `res.header("Access...` does the same as your `web.config` change. You don't need this on the client side. I don't think "Basic ...." is the right way to pass credentials for windows authentication. I rather think the browser provides this automatically and everything only needs to be processed on the server side. See also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732841.aspx

Comment: Removing the "Basic..." gives the same 401 error - Unauthorised access.

Comment: Your question seems to indicate that you get the same error with "Basic..." as well. I'm pretty sure your problem needs a server-side solution. The link I posed in my previous comment states that the browser never gets user credentials (username, password), so where is the point of trying to send them from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the `Authorization` header is correctly sent within your request. If you forgot to import the `Headers` class, the header won't be sent:

```
import {Http, Headers, ...} from 'angular2/http';
```

Another option would be that, since you are in the case of a preflighted request (GET method with the `Authorization` header), an OPTIONS request is sent. In fact, this request is transparently sent by the browser and the credentials are present in it. So you don't have to check security here on the server side. Otherwise you will have a 401 error since the server won't be able to authenticate the request...

See these articles for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Answer (score 1):

I have stumbled upon the same problem when using Angular 2 within an ASP.NET Core solution. For me, I had the explicitly specify `withCredentials: true`:

```
  getSomeModels() {
      return this.http.get(this.apiBasePath + 'models', { withCredentials: true })
          .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

CORS must be enabled on the server side (Web API) and no other changes were required on the client side.

**NOTE:** Server side code to enable CORS (Startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // injected services
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddMvc();

    //db context

    var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
    corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin(); // For anyone access.
    corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("SiteCorsPolicy", corsBuilder.Build());
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
      // middleware configuration

      app.UseCors("SiteCorsPolicy");
}
```

Comment: How does your Server side configuration look like?
I am also trying to access an ASP.NET Core Web API Web Service from an Angular 2 project. I added withCredentials, buiz could not get this working yet (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195858/calling-web-service-using-integrated-windows-authentication-in-angular-2).

Comment: @Alexander - I have added server-side configuration in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Windows authentication in a REST API and make calls from a client with Angular (or any other JavaScript solution), you have to do some configuration on both sides: server and client.

### Server

If you only enable Windows authentication for the REST API from IIS, you are likely to get the `401` error from the client, since browsers make an `OPTIONS` call before making the original call to validate `CORS` access.

[image]

To enable this validation, you must also enable **Anonymous Authentication** in your REST API from IIS.

[image]

And add this exception in the `web.config` file of the REST API:

```
<system.webServer>
.....
<security>
 <authorization>
    <add accessType="Allow" verbs="OPTIONS" users="?" />
    <add accessType="Deny" verbs="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE" users="?" />
 </authorization>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Where Anonymous Authentication is allowed for `OPTIONS` type requests, in order to allow `CORS` validation from the browser. And Anonymous Authentication is denied for the rest of the operations: `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`.

You must consider that the `OPTIONS` method will be enabled for all anonymous calls and you should not use it in your REST API if you are going to validate the authentication.

### Client

On the other hand, in the client you can enable only the Windows authentication in the IIS where it's hosted. And from the JavaScript API call, include the parameter `{ withCredentials: true }`, to specify that the call must include the credentials:

```
callApiPost(url: string, body: object) {
    return this.http
      .post(`${environment.api}/${url}`, body, { withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```