# Angular2 accessing Asp.Net Core Web API 2 using Windows Authentication

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

We have client application developed in Angular2 and WebApi is developed in Asp.Net Core.

We want to integrate both application using Windows Authentication in IIS.

We have integrated WebApi in IIS with Windows Authentication and its working fine i.e. we get User.Identity object when we use WebApi as a separate application.

When we call API from Angular2, it throws error i.e. 401 page not found and if we remove windows authentication from WebApi, it works fine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: "401" means an unauthorized request, not "page not found". Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832236/angular-2-consuming-restful-api-calls-with-windows-authentication