# Calling Web Service using Integrated Windows Authentication in Angular 2

Tags: angular, web-services, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

I have got two applications. One is an ASP.NET Core Web API REST Web Service that is running at http://localhost:59944 and the other one is an ASP.NET Core application using Angular 2 running at http://localhost:63888/.
I want to load JSON Data via the REST Web Service.

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Response with status: 401 null for URL: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Status Code 401 seems to be unauthorized exception.

The Web API Project is using integrated Windows authentication.
If I call the Web API method via the browser it works fine. If I call it via Angular 2 I get the error message.

I have configured ASP.NET Core to allow CORS like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:63888"));

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

The web Ssrvice method call in Angular 2 looks like this:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:59944/api/myWebServiceMethod)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .subscribe(peopleStatistics => {
           return peopleStatistics;
        });
```

How can I do the authentication?
When using Internet Explorer and calling the web service directly I do not have to enter my username and password because the browser uses the credentials of the currently logged in user to authenticate. Is it possible to do this with web Service calls via Angular 2? I mean is it possible to use the web service without the user having to enter his username and Password by using Windows integrated authentication?

Comment: Does Angular 2 solution use `asp-prerender-module` (if yes, it should be configured in `Home\Index.cshtml`)?

Comment: The solution used asp-prerender-module: 
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app> 
I now changed this to <app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>. 
After this the web service calls worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` and replace:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

with

```
<app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loadin‌​g...</app>
```

or remove `asp-prerender-module` if not required:

```
<app>Loading...</app>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using options with web call

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
```

Comment: Where does this get the credentials from? I tryed this but still get the error message.

Comment: you need to pass in the credentials along with the header if it is not managed directly by the service

Comment: you need to pass in the credentials along with the header if it is not managed directly by the service

Comment: I still cannot get this to work. How would you add the credentials? I tryed several things but nothing worked. Is there a good tutorial that expains this?